# Poincare Series of a graded algebra (revisited)

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, graded-algebras, free-lie-algebra

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Let $A = \bigoplus_{i \geq 1}A_i$ be a graded algebra such that the vector spaces $A_i$ are all finite-dimensional. Define the Poincare series of $A$ as the formal series $$P(A) = \sum_{i \geq 0} \operatorname{dim}(A_i)t^i.$$

Prove that $$P(k\{x_1, \dots , x_n \}) = \frac{1}{1 - nt} \text{  and  } P(k [x_1, \dots , x_n ]) = \frac{1}{(1 - t)^n}$$

**Definition 1.**

Let $X$ be a set. Consider the vector space $k\{X\}$ with basis the set of all words $x_{i_{1}} \dots x_{i_{p}}$ in the alphabet $X,$ including the empty word $\emptyset.$ A word will be called a monomial. Define the degree of the monomial $x_{i_{1}} \dots x_{i_{p}}$ as its length $p.$ Concatenation of words defines a multiplication on $k\{X\}$ by $$(x_{i_{1}} \dots x_{i_{p}})(x_{i_{p + 1}} \dots x_{i_{n}}). \quad (2.1)$$

Formula $(2.1)$ equips $k\{X\}$ with an algebra structure, called the free algebra on the set $X.$ If $X = \{x_1 , \dots , x_n \}$ we denote $k\{X\}$ by $k \{x_1, \dots , x_n\}.$

**Definition 2.**

$k\{x_1, \dots , x_n \}/I \cong k[x_1, \dots , x_n]$ where $I = x_i x_j - x_j x_i$ where the later is a commutative algebra.

**My Questions are:**

1- I found on the internet that, for the commutative case, we know that

$$ \dim k^i [x_1, \cdots, x_n] = \sum_{e_1 + \cdots + e_n = i} 1. $$ but I am not sure why this is correct, could anyone show me a proof of this please?

2- Here is the proof of the statement for the commutative ones (I found here [Closed formulas for two Poincaré series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396500/closed-formulas-for-two-poincar%c3%a9-series)) but I am not sure what are the $e_i's$ and why their sum must be $i$? and why the second summation sign disappears in the statement before last? and how is the summation before last leads to the last line?

\begin{align*}
P_{\Bbb{C}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]}(t)
&= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{e_1 + \cdots + e_n = i} t^i \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{e_1 + \cdots + e_n = i} t^{e_1} \cdots t^{e_n} \\
&= \sum_{e_1, \cdots, e_n} t^{e_1} \cdots t^{e_n} \\
&= \frac{1}{(1-t)^n}.
\end{align*}

Could someone help me in answering those questions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis of $\left(k[x_1,\dots,x_n]\right)_i$ is the set of monomials $x_1^{e_1}\dots x_n^{e_n}$ such that $e_1+\dots+e_n=i.$

Any double sum
$\sum_{i\in\Bbb N}\sum_{e_1,\dots,e_n\in\Bbb N\atop e_1+\dots+e_n=i}f(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ is equal to $\sum_{e_1,\dots,e_n\in\Bbb N}f(e_1,\dots,e_n).$

The last equality may be detailed as follows:
$\sum_{e_1,\dots,e_n\in\Bbb N}t^{e_1}\dots t^{e_n}=\left(\sum_{e_1\in\Bbb N}t^{e_1}\right)\dots\left(\sum_{e_n\in\Bbb N}t^{e_n}\right)=\left(\frac1{1-t}\right)^n.$ (This computation is purely *formal*, in *formal series* there is no question of convergence.)

Comment: Can you remind me what a formal series is please? how can we compute it?

Comment: Why your second line is correct, is there a proof for this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series

Comment: The second line is simply: if $(E_i)_{i\in I}$ is a partition of $E$ then $\sum_{i\in I}\left(\sum_{j\in E_i}f(j)\right)=\sum_{j\in E}f(j).$

Comment: Ok, I think I see your point now :)

Comment: But in general, I do not know what are the general steps of calculating the poincare series of a graded algebra, could you please clarify this to me?

Comment: I only used the definition you gave: $P(A) = \sum_{i \geq 0} \operatorname{dim}(A_i)t^i$ for any [graded algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring) $A.$

Comment: like in the non commutative case, we used that dim is n^k ..... what about the dimension in the commutative case, what is it?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4626684/the-dimension-of-the-graded-algebra-of-a-commutative-ring I posted this question for my previous comment